# Resumes generated by Careers are not compatible with parsers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The resume generated by Careers is not at all compatible with any resume parsers. I tried [jobvite](http://recruiting.jobvite.com/) and some other sites.

For example, if I am:

```
Steve Jobs
Cupertino, CA
```

The parsers are interpreting it as something like:

```
Firstname: Jobs
Lastname: Cupertino
```

Funny, but annoying. Please make Careers generate resumes that are parser friendly.